# My homebuilt computer can't awake from sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, sleep, hardware-failure

So I decided to build my own computer about 3 weeks ago. Everything went smooth however I noticed a pretty nasty issue when the computer goes to sleep.
Indeed when it goes to sleep for more than something like 3 hours, trying to awake it through a mouse move or a keyboard press doesn't seem to work.
Actually it's starting to awake (I can see the fans' leds  flashing) but about one second later it shut down and the only way to restart my computer is by rebooting it through a five second press on the power button. I updated all my divices drivers and got all available windows update but it's still doing the same thing.
So I really don't know what's going on.

### My computer :

- Case : Antec DF-35
- PSU : Corsair Enthusiast Series TX850 V2 80PLUS Bronze Certified 850W
- Motherboard : Asus SABERTOOTH P67
- CPU : Intel Core i7-2600
- Graphic card : Sapphire AMD Radeon HD 6970 2GB GDDR5
- DVD reader/writer : LG GH24NS50 24xDVD+R/-R 8xDVD+RW/6xDVD-RW 16xDVD+R
- HDD : Western Digital Caviar Green (WD20EARS) 2000GB (2TB) SATA 3 Gb/s 64MB
- RAM : G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series DDR3 1600MHz (PC3-12800) 8GB (2x4GB)
- Keyboard : Logitech K350 (wireless)
- Mouse : Logitech Mx Revolution (wireless)
- Screens : 2x DELL ST2320L (1 in HDMI and 1 in DVI)
- OS : Windows 7 Ultimate (Service Pack 1)

### What I've tried so far :

- Updated all devices drivers and OS
- Enabling the *EPU power saving* mode in the bios (EFI)
- Enabling the *PLL internal overvoltage* in the bios (EFI)
- Disabling the *hybrid sleep* in "power options" under windows
- Disabling the *hibernate after* in "power options" under windows

And right now, I don't know what to do...

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue, but as a workaround - do you need it to go into sleep mode? can you just change the power options to just have the monitor go off and the HDDs power down, but not put the computer to sleep?

Comment: Does a single short press of the power button wake it up?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. @MaQleod : Actually this is my last resort, I want first to know if it's a hardware or a software issue because I still have the full warranty for all my computer parts.

Comment: @Moab : I tried that and it seems to work but as it crashes randomly after more than 3 hours hibernation, I'll give another try tomorrow in the morning and after work. If it still works then I won't mind to press the power button to wake it up instead of the mouse/keyboard. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Moab : So I tried this morning to wake it up through the power button and it's doing the same thing. No event registered in the event viewer.

Comment: I suspect a PSU issue, or motherboard.

Comment: @Moab : That's also my opinion. I'll get it checked by my provider and I'll post the result.

Comment: Did you try a BIOS update? [Here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/SABERTOOTH_P67/#download) is the link to the BIOS updates you may need.

Comment: @David : Yeah, I also tried to flash the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just like I said, I made my computer checked by pros and it appears that the issue is a known one from Asus motherboards (Asus SABERTOOTH P67) and that many users got hit by this and just turned off their sleep mode.
So, I don't have any other choice than to live with it too. If like me you are in this situation don't wait a minute! use your warranty to replace your motherboard right away. Mine expired 14 days after reception...